# Dynamically moving ruby gem dashing number widgets

Tags: javascript, ruby, gridster, dashing

Working with the ruby gem [Dashing](http://dashing.io) making dashboards. I have multiple number widgets and I'm trying to see if there is a way to move the widgets based on the value. The idea is having the highest number values first. My thoughts are if it is possible maybe it could be done with JS on the dashboards erb file.

Here is an example of html rendered:

```
<h2 class="value" data-bind="current | prettyNumber | prepend prefix | append suffix">128,879</h2>
```

I'm not sure with the send_events that dashing uses or gridster if JS would work to sort my widgets by value.

The other thought is when you manually change the layout you get the "save this layout" and the following:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function() {

  Dashing.cycleGridsterLayout('[[{"col":4,"row":1,"size_x":1,"size_y":1},{"col":5,"row":1,"size_x":1,"size_y":1}]]')
</script>
```

Hoping there might be a simple way to do this. Appreciate any help or further reading on this.

Comment: I wasn't able to figure out a way to move the widgets, but what I did do was rewrite my jobs code so that the widgets were always where I wanted them.